# How to force text to fill 10 lines automatically in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I'm facing this tricky problem, I want to fit the text content to fill exactly n lines, say 10 for example, also fitting the page height. The font size, line spacing... should be automatically changed based on the screen size.

**[image: strong text]**

Using **auto_size_text** dependency was not helpful.

Any solution ideas ?

Comment: warp your text with the expanded widget

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: font size increase with the help of fontSize: Media.query.of(context).size.height / (ex.35). it will manage font according to screen height